# More simplejson AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python

Lots of similar questions on this but I can seem to get the simplest of cases to work.

Code is:

```
retval = urllib2.Request(callstr)
opener = urllib2.build_opener()
f = opener.open(retval)
json = simplejson.load(f)
for item in json:
    print item.get("ExtActionResponse.info")
```

json object seems to get populated correctly.

```
 json
     ExtActionRepsonse  <dict ox7122345...>
        info            u"345167273\n1234:56768"    <----- This is the data I'm expecting
        resultCode      u"0"
        resultStr       u"Success"
        ...etc...
```

But it chokes on the get item call.

```
  print item.get("ExtActionResponse.info")
```

Thanks

Comment: Try: `import pprint` then, `pprint.pprint(json)` after you load.  Let's see what you actually have data-wise.  I think the problem is likely that you need to do something like `item.get('ExtActionResponse', {}).get('info')`

Answer (score 3):

..... What?

```
print json['ExtActionResponse']['info']
```

Comment: Your suggestion worked. Thanks!  The Youtube tutorial I followed was either incorrect or obsolete.